# How to process files that are added on S3 by Lambda and be able to dump data into redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I would like to find out how I can have sample files on my S3 buckets that can be processed by my lambda functions and then be able to dump data into redshift.

I know we can load data from S3 to Redshift using the COPY command from the following aws doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-data.html

What would be the process for files on S3 to Redshift using after being processed by Lambda functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Configure the S3 bucket to trigger your Lambda function when new files are uploaded.
- The Lambda function can copy the file from S3 to the Lambda environment's `/tmp` folder and then perform whatever processing is needed.
- Once the processing is complete, if you want to perform a Redshift `COPY` command, then the Lambda function would need to first copy the new file to a different location in S3, perhaps a completely different bucket, and then issue the `COPY` command to the Redshift cluster. Alternatively the Lambda function could open a connection to the Redshift cluster and issue `INSERT` statements directly.

If you want to decouple the process further, you could have the Lambda function simply copy the final output to another S3 bucket and quit. Then have the second S3 bucket trigger a second Lambda function that issues the `COPY` command to Redshift.

Comment: This answer is good and correct. However a cautionary note should be added to the direct insertion of values into Redshift.  This does work but if frequent, large updates are done this way it will be quite taxing on Redshift.  It is not designed to move data efficiently in this manner and doing this a lot will  impact the leader node and can cause cluster wide slow downs.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i was looking for, appreciate it :)